# Independent identical distributions and conditions for equality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are independent identical distribution, taking values in a finite set $x_1,...,x_n$. Is the following true?

$$Pr\{X=Y: Y\neq Z\}\leq Pr\{X=Y\}$$

What do think about the condition for them when they are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\{X=Y: Y\neq Z\}\subset \{X=Y\} \implies Pr\{X=Y: Y\neq Z\}\leq Pr\{X=Y\}$ by basic axioms of probability.

For your second condition, again we can see that $\{X=Y\} = \{X=Y: Y\neq Z\} \cup \{X=Y: Y=Z\} \implies \{X=Y: Y=Z\} \subset \{X=Y\} \implies Pr\{X=Y: Y=Z\} \leq Pr\{X=Y\}$

In addition $\{X=Y: Y\neq Z\} \cap \{X=Y: Y=Z\} = \emptyset \implies Pr\{X=Y: Y=Z\} + Pr\{X=Y: Y\neq Z\} = Pr\{X=Y\}$